# how to fix the styled-components colors problem

Tags: visual-studio-code, styled-components

I have no color in the styled component, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgooY.png)

I tried re installing styled-componnent but nothing changed, even though it's working ...
it's just a style problem, but still
how can i fix it ? how can i turn it like this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq3Ej.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.